# Сохранить session_id() в cookie на долгое время

Tags: php, cookie

У меня есть простое решение на этот счет.

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'domain.com');
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time()+ (10 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/', 'domain.com');
```

То есть для не активного пользователя id сессии будет сохраняться в cookie 10 дней. Для активного продлеваться на 10 дней каждый запрос.
Разумно ли каждый запрос отправлять `setcookie` с изменением времени? Дополнительные нагрузка и трафик на сервер?